# OpenMP in QT not working

Tags: qt, openmp

h for my code in c++ not I need to integrate with GUI based QT.
the problem I am facing is that in QT I can not get other IDs of thread?

```
omp_set_dynamic(0);
omp_set_nested(3);
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3) 
{

int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
if (ID == 0) 
{ abc();}

if (ID == 1)  
{ abc1();}

if (ID == 2) 
{ abc2();}
}
```

this is working fine without QT platform but not with QT

i have also included this in my .pro file

```
     QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
     QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
     LIBS  += -fopenmp

m using VS2013
```

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "not working fine with Qt"... Like, what error are you getting, exactly, and when?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the OpenMP library:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -openmp
```

Pas de "f" pour VS